# mTLS termination in Java based Vertx Framework

Tags: java, ssl, routes, tls1.2, vert.x

I have a project based on Java based `Vertx` Framework, where I have few internal API calls.
So the flow is I have an API exposed at port `XXXX` (which has TLS configured - `HTTPS`), and inside this API call, I am calling another load balancer which is in `HTTP`. So, I need to terminate the mTLS before calling the Http load balancer.

Below is the sample snippet for VertX `POST` call:

```
private void handleDownstreamRequest(RoutingContext routingContext, String downstreamUrl) {
        VertxUtil.assertOnVertxEventLoop();
        client.postAbs(downstreamUrl) // POST request
            .sendJson(
                routingContext.getBody(),
                ar -> {
                    asyncHttpResponseHandler(ar, routingContext);
                });
    }
```

I wanted to know how to terminate the TLS in Vertx Framework. Is there any inbuilt library exposed by Vertx to terminate mTLS or any sample code snippet will also help.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the HTTP server for
You can configure the HTTP server to use a certificate authority in order to verify the identity of the clients:

```
HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions()
  .setSsl(true)
  .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRED)
  .setTrustStoreOptions(
    new JksOptions()
      .setPath("/path/to/your/truststore.jks")
      .setPassword("password-of-your-truststore")
  );
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(options);
```

The example above assumes you have a Java trust store but Vert.x support PFX/PEM formats too.

Comment: will it help to terminate the mTLS connection ?